# Is it possible to bring a ChildForm on front of another maximized ChildForm without de-maximizing?

Tags: delphi

I have 2 different types of child forms. One type is my main child form, and the other type is like a NOTE in MS Outlook (which is always active in the MDI form).

When my main child form is maximized and I create a new NOTE child form (`TNoteForm.Create(self).Show`), the active maximized child loses its maximized size state and resizes to normal.

Is it possible to keep the maximized state on a child form, when another child becomes active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's simply how Windows MDI works.

The Opera browser allows such a thing, but it doesn't use the built-in MDI functionality of the OS like Delphi does.

One option for you may be to make your note forms *not* be MDI children. Make them be ordinary overlapped windows.